# How to use JAXB annotations in the client side for GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, annotations, jaxb

I wanted to use the JaxB annotation in my class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ItemExtension implements Serializable {
```

But GWT complains when I put it in the client side.

```
 [ERROR] Line 4: The import javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 14: XmlRootElement cannot be resolved to a type
```

Is there a workaround or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12):

I have a project that uses entity classes with both JPA and JAXB annotations in the client-side GWT code. See the section "Overriding one package implementation with another" in the [GWT Documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml).

Let's say your module is in package `com.example.app`. You will need to recreate[1] all JAXB annotation classes in a new package, specifically `com.example.app.jre.java.xml.bind.annotation`; in your module XML file, you then add `<super-source path="jre" />` and you're set.

Note that you don't need to distribute the class files in that package, they are needed solely for the sake of the GWT compiler.

[1]: You can copy them over and adjust all package references.

Comment: If I just move javax.xml.bind.annotation.* I get errors when compiling. One example - `DOMHandler` - `No source code is available for type javax.xml.transform.Result`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need complete source code for all classes/interfaces/annotations that are referenced from the sources. Also copy over the source for `javax.xml.transform.Result`.

Comment: Thanks - I'd copied over everything from javax.xml.bind but needed to just limit it to my dependencies. Are you using this to parse xml or something different? I am trying to parse XML and am how have dependency troubles if I either unmarshal server side (difficulties serializing the jaxb class) or client side (further dependency issues).

Comment: JAXB is an astoundingly bad match for the GWT environment; I would seriously suggest finding some other way to do your (de-)serialization. My use-case was the reuse of my own domain classes in the GWT client, and I needed a way to make the compiler ignore the JAXB-specific annotations. The domain objects were transferred to the client via the normal GWT RPC/serialization mechanism

Comment: Thanks Tassos - I was starting to consider ditching JAXB but this post (and one or two others) gave me a glimmer of hope, but I see that you've got a totally different use case. Thanks for your help, I will try something else :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked these discussions already:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/849c6cc6c9b1467a/cab6b973bbf7d162?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=jaxb+annotations#cab6b973bbf7d162

and

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/6312cedd281b91a9/b1add5932c842ace?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=jaxb+annotations#b1add5932c842ace

Answer (score 1):

I have used this library to do jaxb parsing from within a GWT client

http://code.google.com/p/gwtjaxb/

It is not a full JAXB generator, but it covers everything that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You might find a viable solution here: [GWT with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703737/gwt-with-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my GWT compiler issues by excluding the generated JAXB ObjectFactory from the source in the GWT module XML:

```
<source path="model">
    <exclude name="**/ObjectFactory.*" />
</source>
```