# gwt and jaxb error

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jaxb

I am using eclipse galileo with gwt.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
No source code is available for type javax.xml.namespace.QName; did you forget to inherit a required module?
No source code is available for type javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I tried adding jaxrpc.jar to library path, and also download source of QName.java (i've put it at src/javax/xml/namespace/QName.java). But nothing helped.

Here is the file making me problem - It is auto generated:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.1-b02-fcs 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source     schema. 
// Generated on: 2011.08.31 at 06:12:27 PM IDT 
//


package com.company.jaxb.componentCurrentKPIs;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the com.company.jaxb.componentCurrentKPIs package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

private final static QName _ComponentCurrentKPIs_QNAME = new QName("", "componentCurrentKPIs");

/**
 * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.company.jaxb.componentCurrentKPIs
 * 
 */
public ObjectFactory() {
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link CurrentKPI }
 * 
 */
public CurrentKPI createCurrentKPI() {
    return new CurrentKPI();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ComponentCurrentKPIs }
 * 
 */
public ComponentCurrentKPIs createComponentCurrentKPIs() {
    return new ComponentCurrentKPIs();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ComponentCurrentKPIs }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "componentCurrentKPIs")
public JAXBElement<ComponentCurrentKPIs> createComponentCurrentKPIs(ComponentCurrentKPIs value) {
    return new JAXBElement<ComponentCurrentKPIs>(_ComponentCurrentKPIs_QNAME, ComponentCurrentKPIs.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203878/how-to-use-jaxb-annotations-in-the-client-side-for-gwt